# What is automatic Excel Formula for sum or any other function pattern in large data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a data, which requires continuous change in formula but change is of same pattern.Example of pattern

1. A1/D1
2. (A1+A2)/D1
3. (A1+A2+A3)/D1
   And so on..till A200

Is there an excel formula for recognition of such pattern so that I don't have to fill in formula manually in every cell?

Comment: Is this something you want to drag down a column?

Comment: If in a table, changes to formulas should automatically change in the rest of the column, unless you have have one-off changes in that column

Answer (score 2):

You can use SUM with absolute start and relative end:

```
=SUM($A$1:$A1)/$D$1
```

[image]

Comment: To clarify for OP, the fact that most characters in the range reference have a `$` (making them absolute and unchanging), the second row reference does *not*, meaning it's a relative reference. `$A1` will change as you copy / paste or drag it down. The formula in row 2 will have `$A$1:$A2` and then row 3 will have `$A$1:$A3`, etc.